# Block Youtube videos but not html content

Tags: youtube, blocking

How could i block the display of youtube videos (they are killing our small office) but leave navigation through the youtube HTML pages still active ?? any ideas ?

Comment: you could block flash content from your server . What H/W are you using ?

Comment: this trick will still allow the employees to switch to html5 videos and watch them

Comment: @Shark: Youtube has [HTML5 `<video>` capabilities](http://www.youtube.com/html5), too. Just blocking flash doesn't cut it.

Comment: I think the way to go would just be to block all Youtubes content servers, just find out their URLs.

Comment: I guess it would depend on how smart your employees are. Even if they couldn't get on to Youtube itself they could still watch the videos. It might be better to use logging software or good old fashiioned eyeballs and discipline those violating the policy.

Comment: ytimg.com is the one providing the flash content in youtube sites, I noted this while using noscript addon in firefox. If you can block this site users cant view the videos but still can browse the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Throttle bandwidth to youtube and similar sites.  Seems like the simplest approach both in terms of solving the problem, and the amount of time you spend working on it.